# change div content based on three for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

Hey guys,
I'm new to jQuery/js and having a hard time figuring this out.
There are two fields in a form of mine i want to do some calculations with, what i tried is this:

```
jQuery.fn.calculateit = function(){

    var one = $("#one").val();

    var two = $("#two").val();

    //total
    var total = one + two;
    $("#total").text(total);

};
```

The values "one" and "two" can change at any time, and every time that happens i want the total to change. So I wrote the method above, but I have no idea how to have it called any time something happens with the two fields.

Any ideas?

Maybe I'm on the wrong track, so any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$("#one, #two").change(function() {
    calculateit();
});

var calculateit = function() {

    var one = parseInt($("#one").val(), 10);
    var two = parseInt($("#two").val(), 10);

    //total
    var total = one + two;
    $("#total").text(total);

};
```

Or, if you prefer, you can add `calculateit` to `jQuery.fn` and call it with `$.calculateit()`.

Or, more concisely:

```
$("#one, #two").change(function() {

    var one = parseInt($("#one").val(), 10);
    var two = parseInt($("#two").val(), 10);

    //total
    var total = one + two;
    $("#total").text(total);

});
```

Comment: Or you could make it a little more concise with: `$('#one, #two').change(/*...*/);`

Comment: To be safe, I recommend calling `parseInt()` or `parseFloat` on the returned values before adding them together. Otherwise, you may be concatenating two strings instead of adding their numeric values.

Comment: +1 - but, if you use parseInt, it's very important to include the radix of `10`. ==> `parseInt($("#one").val(), 10)` otherwise numbers that begin with a `0` will be assumed to be octal!

Comment: @Peter: Updated my answer again.

Comment: One more questions: How do I trigger the change event when #one and #two are sliders? It doesn't work the way described below, and I don't know how to call them 'together'..

Comment: @Sled: Looks like sliders also have the `change` function, but if they can't be called together, then just use the first block of code and call `calculateit` separately for each slider change.